# Laravel Nova | Arrow functions | computed property not working in Tool.vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-nova

I have a computed property that is not working correctly. When reading the docs this is how it should be done for Vue 2.x. The code i have:

```html
<template>
<div>
    <button :disabled="isDisabled">Import configurator data</button>
    <input class="input" type="file" id="file" v-on:change="setFile">
</div>
</template>
```

```js
<script lang="js">
export default {
  data: () => {
    return {
      importDisabled: true,
    }
  },

  computed: {
    isDisabled() {
      return this.importDisabled;
    },
  },

  methods: {
    setFile: (e) => {   
      this.importDisabled = false;
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Expected behaviour: Button enables when a file is selected.
Actual behaviour: Button stays disabled.

What am i missing here? A `console.log` within the `isDisabled()` methods shows it is only called once. It is not called after `importDisabled` changes.

Other info:
`vue 2.6.12`
`laravel nova`

Also note: Vue tools does not detect a Vue component in the inspector. But the Vue behaviour is working when loading the tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems arrow functions are bound to the parent context. That was the reason my code did not work. `this` is then not bound to the Vue instance but the parent (Window) which causes it not to work.

Wrong:

```
setFile: (e) => {   
  this.importDisabled = false;
},
```

Right:

```
setFile: function() {   
  this.importDisabled = false;
},
```

More information:
https://codingexplained.com/coding/front-end/vue-js/using-es6-arrow-functions-vue-js